# Unable to build with Support Library on Travis CI/Android SDK v20

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I hope this shouldn't be too challenging, but:

Currently I'm trying to build a project in Android/Travis CI, which you can find over [here](https://travis-ci.org/MinimalBible/MinimalBible). I'm trying to use the Android L developer preview, and build with Travis-CI. I was hoping that using the [Gradle SDK Manager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin) plugin would allow me to do this. Unfortunately, it doesn't. I don't know if my build.gradle file is set up improperly, or what, but I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

[Build error](https://travis-ci.org/MinimalBible/MinimalBible/builds/29204239):

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_testConfigDebugCompile'.
        > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+.

Required by:

MinimalBible:app:unspecified
```

[build.gradle](https://github.com/MinimalBible/MinimalBible/blob/master/app/build.gradle):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.10.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'org.bspeice.minimalbible'
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
}
```

Let me know if any further information is required.

Comment: Looks like the required SDK tools/version may be coming soon:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin/issues/38
https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin/commit/c19ea53acbbe3a35b316f766fb1065dc983bac99

Unfortunately for now it looks like the only option is running tests locally.

Comment: And I can confirm that the build is now in fact working again. Travis-CI should be good to go, post an issue if you're having one.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //force complie with 20.0.0
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'){force = true}
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.1'
}
```